# How to compose two Flux<> Objects into one

Tags: java, project-reactor

I am kind of new to reactive programming to begin with. After attending some talks about reactor and spring 5.0 I wanted to try this programming model on my own.

I have an application which builds two Flux objects from different API's using WebClient. I want to compose this 2 objects into one and return it to the user.

The code example would look like this:

```
public class User {
  private String username;
  //getters and setters
}

public class Address {
  private String street;
  //getters and setters;
}

public class CompleteUser {
  private String username;
  private String address;
  //getters and setters
}
```

And now in my handler method:

```
final Flux<User> = WebClient.create()...;
final Flux<Address> = WebClient.create()...;
final Flux<CompleteUser> = //somehow compose this two types into one
```

What method from reactor API should I use to achieve this? I found some methods to compose objects like combineLatest however in this case I want to compose exactly first item of first Flux with first item of second Flux and etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Flux.zip` static method is exactly what you are looking for. For combination of 2 sources, you can provide a `BiFunction` to produce the result.

```
Flux<CompleteUser> complete = Flux.zip(fluxUser, fluxAddress, (u, a) -> new CompleteUser(u, a));
//if the ctor perfectly matches, you can also use CompleteUser::new
```

Comment: What in case I have more sources? For example, when I need to fetch data from N repositories and then create a new object from all of the data. Isn't there anything better than  'zip'? It looks awkward when `TupleN` is used.